# No tests available on mocha

Tags: meteor, mocha.js, velocity

I have 2 samples Mocha web tests which I'm trying to run using Velocity. For some reason I don't see any tests running.

This is what I did

```
meteor create test
meteor add mike:mocha
meteor
```

I see the mark at the right top of my screen, I can add tests with a button, so I did it.
My architecture looks like this

```
.meteor
client
lib
public
server
tests
     Mocha
          Client
                sampleClientTest.js
          Server
                sampleServerTest.js
```

Finally, my console is empty, both on windows and chrome

Thoughts ?

Answer (score 0):

I realize I'm 5 months late, but I'll answer in case someone else runs into this problem.

The problem you're having might be related to [this issue](https://github.com/mad-eye/meteor-mocha-web/issues/163), the tests seem to work when you visit the mirror listed on the terminal after you start the server.

Try opening localhost:3000 and then the mirror in a new tab

Comment: This may theoretically answer the question, but it would be best to include the essential parts of the answer here for future users, and provide the link for reference. [Link-dominated answers](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231) can become invalid through [link rot](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot).